# What is the return of the yield block on a call to a parameter chained with a method from a Gem iterated with #each?

Tags: ruby, methods, rubygems, yield

I'm attempting to understand a method used in a Mastermind Game, and I don't understand what the yield block is producing; or the return of the actual method...

Here's the code:

```
#lib/mastermind/gameboard.rb

require 'colorize'

def colorize(set, is_color_code)
  colors = []
  text = is_color_code ? "0" : "."
  set.colors.each { |color| colors.push(text.public_send(color.to_sym)) }
  colors.join(' ')
end
```

My primary question is: If `#colors` returns an Array of all the keys from a hash, and I'm simply pushing the local `text` variable to the local `colors` Array, joined with `#public_send(color.to_sym)`, won't the return of the `#colorize` method here be an Array of either "0".color or ".".color?

I think it needs to be said that `#colorize` is a method in the Colorize Gem, however, this `#colorize` method is part of a separate class in the [project I'm reviewing.](https://github.com/JonathanYiv/mastermind/blob/master/gameboard.rb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the method line by line to see what's going on.

```
def colorize(set, is_color_code)
  colors = [] # instantiate an array
  text = is_color_code ? "0" : "."  # ternary assignment if is_color_code == true || false
  # set.colors is an array of strings like ['white', 'white', 'white', 'white']
  # set.colors.each { |color| colors.push(text.public_send(color.to_sym)) }
  # line above this refactored to comment
  set.colors.each do |color|
    # color.to_sym # convert the string to symbol so 'white' becomes :white
    # you must pass a symbol to public_send 
    # so this is sending the name of the color to the string as provided by the gem.
    colors.push( text.public_send(color.to_sym) ) # push the return of that into array
  end 
  # In Ruby the method always returns whatever the output of the last line returns.
  colors.join(' ') # returns the colors array a string joined by spaces
end
```

In this case the colorize method is defined inside the `GameBoard` class. So when that method is called on an instance of `GameBoard` it will behave as it was defined to do. Where as `'blue'.colorize(:blue)` here `.colorize` method extends the `String` class to respond with the color codes of the color symbol passed

Example

```
'blue'.colorize(:blue) # same as 'blue'.blue
 =>"\e[0;34;49mblue\e[0m"
```

Refactored version

```
def colorize(set, is_color_code)
  text = is_color_code ? "0" : "."
  set.colors
     .map { |color| text.public_send(color.to_sym) }
     .join(' ')
end
```

Comment: To clarify the Array object of set.colors: if `set` is an Array of strings before `#colorize` is invoked, what is the `#colors` method doing when `#colorize` is invoked?

Comment: You've got some misinformation about `public_send` in there. The method is not removed from Ruby and is still present in the newest 2.6.4 version. The difference is that [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-public_send) only calls public methods while [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Object.html#method-i-send) can also call private or protected methods.

Comment: @3limin4t0r right, what was I thinking, it was defined forever. Updated, thanks.

Comment: @J.R.BobDobbs inside the method here `.colors` is not "doing" anything.  It's just a local array defined to be used in the local `.each` loop.  I will refactor it to use `.map` instead

Comment: You're also better of using using the same method invocation tactic for your example. For `text.public_send(color.to_sym)` I would use the example `'blue'.blue #=> ...` since that's how it's technically called. Although I agree that `text.colorize(color)` might be more fitting (especially while dynamically colouring).

Comment: @lacostenycoder Maybe that's where my confusion is coming from; The usage of `colors` as a local Array. Will you please confirm my confusion? The `colors` in `set.colors.each` is NOT a call to the `#colors` method from the Colorize Gem...

Comment: `set.colors` is an instance variable assigned to instance of `Hint` or `ColorCode` which are the objects passed as first argument to your `colorize` method. See `initialize` methods defined in [Hint](https://github.com/JonathanYiv/mastermind/blob/master/hint.rb#L4) and [ColorCode](https://github.com/JonathanYiv/mastermind/blob/master/colorcode.rb#L4). So you are correct that `set.colors` has nothing to do with the colorize gem.

Comment: Oh wow. I can get on with my life now. Thanks for giving me my freedom back.

Comment: Due to the duck-typing nature of Ruby you can't know what the `set` parameter is. If you want to know what the content of `set` is you can either add some debugging in the `colorize` method, or simply look at the [usage](https://github.com/JonathanYiv/mastermind/blob/dc36455a31969479170627ec60b79993f6764d35/gameboard.rb#L14).

Comment: @3limin4t0r yep thanks that's exactly what I meant to do.  Updated.

Comment: In an effort to understand the `#colorize` method...I was abstracting too far away from the original usage of what `set` would be passed as -- either a ColorCode or Hint object -- and was simplifying into confusion...

Comment: when in doubt, try to find where the method in question is being called as explained by @3limin4t0r  in previous comment.  Glad it makes sense now.